# Reading string value from excel sheet

Tags: python, python-2.7

The API function `psspy.two_winding_chg_4` requires an input using single quotes ' ' as shown below in that function(3rd element of the array)[image: excel sheet 2]I am receiving an integer error when reading from my CSV sheet. Its giving me problems reading the last column. I know theres characters in the last column but how do I define `digit` as a character.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\RoszkowskiM\Desktop\win4.py", line 133, in <module>
psspy.two_winding_chng_4(from_,to,'%s'%digit,[_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i],[_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f, max_value, min_value,_f,_f,_f],[])
File ".\psspy.py", line 25578, in two_winding_chng_4
TypeError: an integer is required
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'T1'

for row in data:
    data_location, year_link, from_, to, min_value,max_value,name2,tla_2,digit = row[5:14]
    output = 'From Bus #: {}\tTo Bus #: {}\tVMAX: {} pu\tVMIN: {} pu\t'
    if year_link == year and data_location == location and tla_2==location:
       from_=int(from_)
       to=int(to)
       min_value=float(min_value)
       max_value=float(max_value)
       digit=int(digit)
       print(output.format(from_, to, max_value, min_value))
      _i=psspy.getdefaultint()
      _f=psspy.getdefaultreal()
       psspy.two_winding_chng_4(from_,to,'%s'%digit,[_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i],[_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f, max_value, min_value,_f,_f,_f],[])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what *psspy.two_winding_chng_4()* is using internally.

1. If you can specify a  regex *( like r'[A-Za-z][0-9]')* to match the final column.
2. The other option is to read it as string and extract the details from the data at a later instance.

Option 1 would be recommended since it would enable a more reusable and robust.
*psspy.two_winding_chng_4()* function. Option 2 is recommended since psspy appears to be a third party library.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: Is psspy.py standard libray?

Comment: http://www.whit.com.au/blog/python-libraries-for-psse-python-training/   Here is the link to the libraries for `psspy`

Comment: If the two_winding_chng_4() is internal function. you can't go with Option 1. You will have to go with option 2 : read it as string them extract value with regex.   Add a psse py or such label to the question. This is specific to psspy.

Comment: Mark, the psspy module, have you written it, if not where can I download just the psspy.py file/

Comment: it should be on the website I provided earlier

Comment: It has py setup, matplotlib, numpy, pywin32.